# Display other value Columns when displaying duplicate values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I do have a query which gives me Duplicate values but I got stuck where the other column is not providing the data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.Name
, S.RollNumber
, COUNT(S.RollNumber) as [Count]
, S.Subject1
, S.Subject2 
FROM DataMining.dbo.StudentsData S

WHERE StartDate >= '20210309'
AND StartDate <= '20210310'
GROUP BY S.Name, S.RollNumber, COUNT(S.RollNumber), S.Subject1, S.Subject2 
HAVING COUNT(S.RollNumber) > 1
```

Adding an example of data present:

```
Name   |  RollNumber | Subject1 | Subject2

JOHN H       105         Math     Chemistry
JOHN H       105         Physics  English
JESSI U      100         English  French
JESSI U      100         Math     French
JESSI U      100         English  Physics
RIO MATH     118         Math     English
MATTHEW U    103         Physics  English
MATTHEW U    103         Math     Chemistry
JACKI M      107         English  Physics
```

The above above data my code gives me the below result

```
Name   |  RollNumber | Count | Subject1 | Subject2

JOHN H       105         2       NULL       NULL
JESSI U      100         3       NULL       NULL
MATTHEW U    103         2       NULL       NULL
```

These records has values in Subject1 and Subject2
Eg: RollNumber 105 has values in Subject1 and Subject 2 (2 values each i.e., Math, Physics as Subject1 and Chemistry, English as Subject 2)

But the result for the query gives the values as `Null`

How to over come this and make the results to display as below Example which is Expected Result:

```
Name   |  RollNumber | Count | Subject1 | Subject2

JOHN H       105         2       Math     Chemistry
JOHN H       105         2       Physics  English
```

Comment: Having a `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` in a query is always a sure sign that either the `GROUP BY` is wrong, it the `DISTINCT` is redundant. Grouping on `COUNT(S.RollNumber)`, however, makes no sense. You don't group on the value you are aggregation on.

Comment: Please provide sample data as well as the results.  In addition, your query as written will produce an error, because of the `COUNT()` in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The query gave me the above results which I have displayed (as sample data) :)

Comment: @Larnu Distinct will remove the duplicate records however I'm looking for the Duplicate values present specifically under a particular column here in which it is the RollNumber

Comment: @RealGem there should be no duplicate "records" (rows?) as the `GROUP BY` already puts the data into distinct sets. If you have duplicate rows then your `GROUP BY` is likely wrong (again, the fact you have `COUNT(S.RollNumber)` in the `GROUP BY` is a strong indicator of this).

Comment: Wait, the input data has a column called "Count"?

Comment: @tymtam it's an Alias name for the count of Roll number which I gave

Comment: Your input example doesn't have any duplicates. All will have count of 1

Comment: @tymtam This query is specifically targeting the Roll number which got repeated post which after I filter the duplicates I want those other columns results which belongs to the repeated records(based on Roll number)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. I updated my answer. The key is that you want the original rows with an extra value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you want the original rows with extra count grouped by Name and RolNumber
and filter out all rows for which the count is <2

Here's what could work:

```
SELECT 
S.Name
, S.RollNumber
, X.Count
, Subject1
, Subject2  
FROM DataMining.dbo.StudentsData S
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT Name, RollNumber, Count(*) as Count 
   FROM DataMining.dbo.StudentsData 
   GROUP BY Name, RollNumber ) x 
  on x.Name = S.Name and x.RollNumber = S.RollNumber
WHERE StartDate >= '20210309'
AND StartDate <= '20210310'
AND x.Count > 1
```

Comment: This query is specifically targeting the Roll number which gets repeated and post which after I filter the duplicates I want those other columns results which belongs to the repeated records(based on Roll number) and don't want to display as Null